# JDialog goes behind main application Frame when responding to JOptionPane's OptionDialog

Tags: swing

In my application, I launch a JDialog to get some values from user. As part of validation, I through error message to the user using JOptionPane's showOptionDialog method. When user click s on the OK button, the JDialog goes behind the main application window.
Can someone point out what causes this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod I've fixed the issue and given my answer. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that a `parentComponent` was not passed to the [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) dialog. I passed my dialog object as the actual `parentComponent` parameter when invoking the dialog, and that solved my problem.